# width / border-width (CSS)

Tags: html, css

So, I have an error. I was wondering if someone recognizes It.

```
div.top { 
    border-top: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #333;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 50px;
    border: solid;    
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-width: 100%;
}
```

[tried to fix the top left corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYmDV.png)

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score -1):

Actually it is not easy to get like that, it looks like the parent element has a padding or maybe the child. I recommend you to start your projects using a normalize CSS code like this one:

https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

This normalization code will help you to **"clear"** a lot of the **"weird"** things that happens in our browsers.

UPDATE:

I did not see your code. Do not use **with: 100%** with border values because it will make your container "bigger" than 100%. Use **display: block**, and your border.